# Date Range Picker loses range when closed

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker

I am struggling with an issue.  I want to close the date range picker when a user starts scrolling down the page.  I am using this plugin to create the date range picker:

http://www.daterangepicker.com/

```
$(function() {
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    timePickerIncrement: 30,
    locale: {
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'
    },
    ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment()],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
       'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
       'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('input[name="daterange"]').length) {
        $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker("close");
  }
});
```

});

I've created a fiddle to show the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/ccgorman/rLnycn80/

I have a bit of JS that closes the date range picker when the user scrolls, but as you can see, when you scroll back up and open it up again all the buttons, like Today, Yesterday...are gone, any idea how I close the picker without losing these buttons?

Answer (score 0):

**Change this line:**
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker("close");
**with:**
$('input[name="daterange"]').data('daterangepicker').hide();